# Save response type "Content-Type : text/javascript" in text file

Tags: javascript, c, content-type

I am getting some response of HTTP request.

Response header is "Content-Type : text/javascript" and some response body.

I want to save this response body in text file as "a.txt".

Can I do it ? I have "C" files in which I have to do it.

Regards PJ

Comment: Should this not be tagged C? Tagging it now.

Answer (score 1):

There are many [file operations](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/) which allow you to save a buffer into a file.

PS: The above solution as simple as it may sound, your question is still vague. What is the exact problem you are trying to solve?